# Grab the last iteration of a foreach loop (where the last iteration needs to differ)

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Is there a way I can determine the last iteration of a foreach loop, and implement some different code?

I'm trying to iterate through an array and output parts of it into a table.

Here is an example of my array:

```
array(2) {
    [0]=> array(3) {
        [date]=> string(10) "2013-09-18"
        [title]=> string(75) "Ready For Retina HD: Create Pixel-Perfect Assets For Multiple Scale Factors"
        [filepath]=> string(74) "ready-for-retina-hd-create-pixel-perfect-assets-for-multiple-scale-factors"
    }
    [1]=> array(3) {
        [date]=> string(10) "2010-10-20"
        [title]=> string(40) "Taking A Closer Look At Tech Conferences"
        [filepath]=> string(40) "taking-a-closer-look-at-tech-conferences"
    }
}
```

For each part, I want to output the `title`, then I want to output the `filepath` as a link, in two different places (once is a "view" link and the other is an "edit" link).

I need to run through the array and make each of these three items into a table row, so I've implemented a counter which inserts `</tr><tr>`every 3 items, to cut off the old row and start a new one.

It works great the only problem is in the case of the last item, because it will always open a new row due to the last `<tr>`

How can I restructure this so that it doesn't open the row on the last count?

```
echo "<table border='2'><tbody><tr>";
foreach ($myarray as $post){
    // Adds to count, outputs title
    echo "<td>" . $post['title'] . "</td>";
    $rowcounter++;

    // Adds to count, outputs filepath with "view"
    echo "<td><a href='../posts/post-" . $post['filepath'] . "'>View</a></td>";
    $rowcounter++;

    // Adds to count, outputs filepath with "edit"
    echo "<td><a href='../posts/post-" . $post['filepath'] . "?edit=true'>Edit</a></td>";
    $rowcounter++;

    // Tests the count
    echo 'rowcounter = ' . $rowcounter;
    if ($rowcounter == "3"){
        $rowcounter = 0;
        echo "</tr><tr>";
    }
}
echo "</tr></tbody></table>";
```

Comment: Your question title doesn't match your question. Change your loop to `foreach($myarray as $key => $post){` and then to see if you are on the last item `if($key == (count($myarray)-1)){`. Though there are better solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Render your `<tr>`s only inside your loop, rather than opening and closing before and after, respectively.

As far as I can tell, there's no need for you to keep count of your 'rows' (which by the way are columns). You iterate for each row so all of your per-row markup should come between your `foreach` curly braces:

```
echo "<table border='2'><tbody>";
foreach ($myarray as $post){ // One iteration per row
    echo '<tr>'; // Row STARTS here.

    echo "<td>" . $post['title'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><a href='../posts/post-" . $post['filepath'] . "'>View</a></td>";
    echo "<td><a href='../posts/post-" . $post['filepath'] . "?edit=true'>Edit</a></td>";

    echo '</tr>'; // Row ENDS here.
}
echo "</tbody></table>";
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes much more sense :)

Comment: Glad to have helped (:

Answer (score 0):

I recommend George's answer for this but for future reference you could alternatively either use a for loop instead of a foreach:

```
foreach ($i=0; $i < count($myarray); $i++){
    $post = $myarray[$i];
    ...
```

then check $i against the count of $myarray

or you could add a row count to the loop which increments on each iteration and do a check against the number of rows in $myarray